# HTML table not formatting properly in C#

Tags: c#, html, .net, visual-studio, html-email

I'm developing an API in .NET with C#. I'm trying to send Emails with a proper format (when a delegation rule assigned to a particular user.)

This is the code block I've tried so far.

```
            strings.Add("email_delegation_rule_assigned", "Delegation rule assigned ");
            strings.Add("email_delegation_rule_assigned_body",
                "Hi {senderName},<br/><br/>"
                + "The following Workflow Request/s have been submitted for your approval, in the absence of {assignerUserName} from {delegateFromDate} to {delegateFromTo}.<br/><br/>"
                + "<style>table, th, td {border: 1px solid black; }</style>"
                + "<style>th {background-color:#73c1e1; }</style>"
                + "<table>" +
                "<tr>" +
                "<th> Delegation Req# </th>" +
                "<th>Delegation<table><tr><td>From User</td><td>To User</td></tr></table></th>" +
                "<th>Effective Period<table><tr><td> From </td><td> To </td></tr></table></th>" +
                "<th> List of Workflows </th>" +
                "</tr>" +
                "<tr>" +
                "<td>1</td>" +
                "<td><table><tr><td> {assignerUserName} </td><td> You </td></tr></table></td>" +
                "<td><table><tr><td>{delegateFromDate}</td><td>{delegateFromTo}</td></tr></table></td>" +
                "<td>{workflowName}</td>" +
                "</tr>" +
                "</table><br/><br/>" +
                "For further information please contact<br/><br/>" +
                "You can view the Delegation details by clicking on the link below, using Flowdoh Workspace/Form Designer<br/><br/>" +
                "Thank you!<br/>" +
                "Warm Regards,<br/>" +
                "Enadoc Team<br/><br/>"
                );
```

I'm getting Emails in this format, which is a wrong format.

[image]

my Emails should look like this...

[image]

How can I properly align lines when divide a single column into two columns? The **th** column doesn't align with the **td** values. 
..and I need to have single lines in the table. 
(ignore background colors in headers)

Please help me out. I really appreciate your responses. Thank u in advance!

Comment: I would suggest a totally different layout, because these are not going to work for mobiles. Try a card UI layout, as discussed here: https://medium.com/@nathankeenmelb/responsive-datatables-through-card-ui-design-for-email-aca6f3c395a2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use colspan and rowspan attributes instead of separate tables to do your layout. Here is an example

```
<style>table, th, td {border: 1px solid black; }</style>
<style>th {background-color:#73c1e1; }</style>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th rowspan="2"> Delegation Req# </th>
    <th colspan="2">Delegation</th>
    <th colspan="2">Effective Period</th>
    <th rowspan="2"> List of Workflows </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>From User</th><th>To User</th>
    <th>From</th><th>To</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>{assignerUserName}</td>
    <td> You </td>
    <td>{delegateFromDate}</td>
    <td>{delegateFromTo}</td>
    <td>{workflowName}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/cx58syn0/

Comment: @schewechel Thank you so much. Do you know how to design the table with single lines? rather than double lines?

Comment: Colspan does not work well in email clients https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/columns/column-span/

Comment: @M.Sachintha I don't know of a way to make a header like that work in one row instead of two if that is what you are asking. If you mean the borders around the cells, you should be able to fix that with some styling `table {border-collapse: collapse;}` Jsfiddle with this change if you want to see it. (https://jsfiddle.net/qxoktm40/)

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need this one. [image]

So HTML code would be

```
    <table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th scope="col" rowspan="2">Delegation Req#</th>
    <th scope="col" colspan="2">Delegation</th>
    <th scope="col" colspan="2">Effective Period</th>
    <th scope="col" rowspan="2">List of workflows</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>From User</td>
    <td>To User</td>
    <td>From</td>
    <td>To</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">1</th>
    <td>Admin</td>
    <td>You</td>
    <td>16/16/2020 18:30:00 PM (UTC)</td>
    <td>17/16/2020 18:30:00 PM (UTC)</td>
    <th scope="row">Workflow 06/15001</th>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <th scope="row">2</th>
    <td>Admin1</td>
    <td>You2</td>
    <td>18/16/2020 18:30:00 PM (UTC)</td>
    <td>19/16/2020 18:30:00 PM (UTC)</td>
    <th scope="row">Workflow 06/15001</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you @Damith for your response. Your answer seems identical.